# Почему не умирает поток в java?

Tags: java, многопоточность

Добрый день. Разбираю код из книжки (чат клиент). Почему `Thread readerThread` не завершает своего выполнения? метод run() лежит внизу стека, по идее он должен выполниться и завершить работу, однако все входящие сообщения обрабатываются и выводятся.

```
public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            while((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("read " + message);
                incoming.append(message + "\n");
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
```

Насколько я понимаю если буфер пуст, то цикл завершается и метод собственно тоже, однако как только приходит сообщение от сервера оно все равно обрабатывается.
Полный код:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Client {

    JTextArea incoming;
    JTextField outgoing;
    BufferedReader reader;
    PrintWriter writer;
    Socket sock;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Client client = new Client();
        client.go();
    }

    public void go() {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Chat Client");
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
        incoming = new JTextArea(15,20);
        incoming.setLineWrap(true);
        incoming.setWrapStyleWord(true);
        incoming.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane qScroller = new JScrollPane(incoming);
        qScroller.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
        qScroller.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        outgoing = new JTextField(20);
        JButton sendButton = new JButton("Send");
        sendButton.addActionListener(new SendButtonListener());
        mainPanel.add(qScroller);
        mainPanel.add(outgoing);
        mainPanel.add(sendButton);
        setUpNetworking();

        Thread readerThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
        readerThread.start();

        frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, mainPanel);
        frame.setSize(400,500);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void setUpNetworking() {
        try {
            Socket sock = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 5000);
            InputStreamReader streamReader = new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream());
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);
            writer = new PrintWriter(sock.getOutputStream());
            System.out.println("networking established");
        } catch(IOException ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }

    public class SendButtonListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ev) {
            try {
                writer.println(outgoing.getText());
                writer.flush();
            } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
            outgoing.setText("");
            outgoing.requestFocus();
        }
    }

public class IncomingReader implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
        String message;
        try {
            while((message = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println("read " + message);
                incoming.append(message + "\n");
            }
        } catch(Exception ex) {ex.printStackTrace();}
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Может добавить блок finally и там убить поток?

Comment: Мне не надо убивать, мне надо понять почему это работает

Comment: Работает потому, что поток не завершается по завершении выполнения метода.

Comment: Так по итогу метод завершается? Тогда как продолжают считываться сообщения?

Comment: Так сообщения считываются на стороне сервера? Где код сервера?

Comment: Видимо  `reader.readLine()` ожидает сообщения и никогда не возвращает null.

Comment: Т.е. поток блокируется пока не придет сообщение?

Answer (score 0):

Там, где вы получаете

```
Thread readerThread = new Thread(new IncomingReader());
readerThread.start();
```

сохраните эту ссылку и сделайте кнопку "Отключиться", обработчиком будет прерывание потока:

```
readerThread.interrupt();
```

Это как раз возможность послать InterruptedException в то время, пока поток висит на методе `reader.readLine()`